# An error occured while updating some of the page status :0

Tags: xpages

i've started to have the error message *"An error occured while updating some of the page unable to load http ://xxxxxx  status:0"*
when i change from xpage to xpage in my application,it wasn't appear in the beginning , but it started to appear recently , i thing when i open a page and save it !!

Comment: That message typically indicates that a partial refresh event is still pending when the user navigates away. Check to see if you have any events that are taking longer than they should to complete.

Comment: According to @Tim's comment, look into network tab of FireBug (or alternatives in other browsers).